# Do I understand this "method" method right?

Tags: ruby

While starting [RubyMonk](http://rubymonk.com/) level 2, I see this:

```
class Calculator
  def add(a, b)
    return a + b
  end
end

addition_method = Calculator.new.method("add")
addition        = addition_method.to_proc

puts addition.call(5, 6)
```

and never having seen `method` before, I consulted [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-method)

So the understanding I have now, is:

If you want to steal a method from a class, and make it into a `proc` (`lambda`?), you stick the `method` in there before the name of the class method you desire, which you then surround with quotes or write as a symbol.

Is this the correct way to think about it? Or is it at least the primary use of `Object#method`?

Comment: A lambda is just a special kind of proc (`lambda {}.class #=> Proc`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have the right idea.  More generally, the `method` method is just a way of representing a Ruby method as a [Method object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Method.html), and that could be useful for many reasons because objects are useful.

There is some extraneous stuff in that example code.  Here is another example:

```
def add(a)
  a + a
end

m = method(:add)  # => #<Method: Object#add>
m.call(4)         # => 8
```

Here is another example where it is useful:

```
def good?(n)
  n > 5
end

[1, 4, 9].select(&method(:good?))   # => [9]
```

Comment: Thanks sir. That will hold me over for the next few exercises.

Comment: @dwilbank A footnote: `&method` converts a method to block

Answer (score 0):

Essentially yes. The `method` method lets you "package up" the method *and* its receiver into a single object of class `Method`. The receiver is the object you called `.method` on. A `Method` object is also called a "bound" method because it's bound (attached) to a receiver.

Example:

```
class Car
  attr_accessor :make, :model

  def initialize(make, model)
    @make, @model = make, model
  end

  def drive(speed)
    puts "#{@make}-#{@model} drove with speed #{speed}"
  end
end
```

Create an instance:

```
car1 = Car.new('Toyota', 'Corolla')
```

Grab the method and call it:

```
car1drive = car1.method(:drive)
# Outputs "Toyota-Corolla drove with speed 5"
car1drive.call(5)
```

Note how we don't have to convert it to a `proc` in order to use `call` on it.

**Receiver binding**

To demonstrate how the method is still bound to its receiver, we modify the receiver. Notice how the `Method` still depends on the object it came from. I.e. creating the `Method` did *not* take a snapshot of the receiver's state, but consults the receiver every time it's called.

```
car1.model = 'Rav4'
# Outputs "Toyota-Rav4 drove with speed 5"
car1drive.call(5)
```

We can also retrieve the receiver:

```
car1drive.receiver == car1  # true
```

**Usage as a block**

It can be used in place of a block by using `&` (which implicitly calls `to_proc`). This works nicely because `each` yields one argument to the block, and our `car1drive` method also takes one argument.

```
# Outputs:
# Toyota-Rav4 drove with speed 1
# Toyota-Rav4 drove with speed 2
# Toyota-Rav4 drove with speed 3
[1,2,3].each(&car1drive)
```

**Unbound methods**

We can also get an unbound method and bind that to another `Car`.

`unbind` returns a brand new `UnboundMethod`; it doesn't change the bound method.

```
# This gives us an UnboundMethod.
# It can't be called; it's like a disembodied spirit.
# This doesn't change car1drive at all.
unbound_drive = car1drive.unbind

car2 = Car.new('Chevy', 'Cruze')
car2drive = unbound_drive.bind(car2)
# Outputs "Chevy-Cruze drove with speed 5"
car2drive.call(5)
```

You can also get the same `UnboundMethod` as the above by using the `Car` class directly:

```
unbound_drive = Car.instance_method(:drive)
```

**Calling a superclass method that has been overridden in a subclass**

Here's one nice trick you can do to call an overridden method. Let's say you have a subclass that overrides a method:

```
class Jalopy < Car
  def drive(speed)
    puts "The ailing #{@make}-#{@model} drove with speed #{speed}"
  end
end

jal1 = Jalopy.new('Toyota', 'Corolla')
# Outputs "The ailing Toyota-Corolla drove with speed 5"
jal1.drive(5)

# I don't like the overridden output, give me the original instead!
unbound_car_drive = Car.instance_method(:drive)
car_drive_on_jal1 = unbound_car_drive.bind(jal1)

# Outputs "Toyota-Corolla drove with speed 5"
car_drive_on_jal1.call(5)
```

We can only do this because `jal1` is a `Car` (`jal1.is_a?(Car)` is `true`)

I don't recommend using the above in an actual application, because it makes code very hard to manage - but sometimes it helps with troubleshooting.